# Definition of multipile double words in assembly

Tags: assembly

I've got the next definition (A part of an actual question):

```
Turkey: mov ebx, Ygg
        call foo
foo: ;;Does something
Dra: dd    0xffff, Sil, Sil, Sil
Ygg: dd    0x11, Dra, Sil Dra
Sil: dd    3, 0, 0
```

Now i don't understand how do i actually draw the memory of this one.

I mean, ebx, will get an address to the start of Ygg [Points at 0x11 i guess?], But then how do i navigate?

What do i have in the next bytes? Address to Dra, Sil, And Dra again?

```
Ygg: dd    0x11, Dra, Sil, Dra
```

But then what happens when i do something like:

```
mov ebx, [ebx+4]
```

I know my questions are a bit unfocused, But it's because i can't "see" how does it look in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example if the memory location of "Dra" starts at offset 0x0000 in the data segment:

```
mov ebx,Ygg     ; ebx = 0x00000010
mov ebx,[ebx+4] ; ebx = 0x00000000 (second dword of DS:Ygg)
```

Data segment starts with offset 0x0000:

```
0x0000 Dra dd 0x0000ffff, 0x00000020, 0x00000020, 0x00000020
0x0010 Ygg dd 0x00000011, 0x00000000, 0x00000020, 0x00000000
0x0020 Sil dd 0x00000003, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
```

Comment: So by your explanation: If i define SIL a couple of times in the same label, It's points to the same place? Meanning changing the values in the memory of SIL will affect all the others, right?

Answer (score 1):

> What do i have in the next bytes? Address to Dra, Sil, And Dra again?

Yes. each address stored as 4 bytes

> mov ebx, [ebx+4]

An address is calculated, from ebx+4.  4 bytes are read from that address and copied into ebx.

Maybe it helps to think of "addresses" not as something special. They are just numbers, too. You only happen to be able to read or write to the location, corresponding to the value of those numbers.